# Assign type to destructured variable that is also renamed

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

How can I use destructuring assignment while assigning to a new variable name *and* set a type? An example of this is here:

```
const {
  Script: script, // string
  EstimatedDuration: estimated_duration, // number
  ActualDuration: actual_duration, // number
} = response.data[0];
```

My first instinct was to add `<string>` or `as string` to the RHS, which didn't work. Trying other variations failed as well.

Is this something that is possible, or am I SOL with regard to type checking on these variables? I'd like to use destructuring and not `const script: string = response.data[0].Script` and similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it if you're willing to type everything out twice.

```
// replace with your response object above
declare const responseObject: {
    Script: any,
    EstimatedDuration: any,
    ActualDuration: any,
};

const {
    Script: script,
    EstimatedDuration: estimated_duration,
    ActualDuration: actual_duration,
}: { 
    Script: string, 
    EstimatedDuration: number, 
    ActualDuration: number 
} = responseObject;

console.log(script, estimated_duration, actual_duration);
```

At that point though you're just writing the actual type declaration, so you could also make that type below an `interface` somewhere for easy access.

Comment: I'm hesitantly accepting this, as it's _incredibly_ verbose. I'd obviously much prefer a shorter solution, but unless an answer of sorts is posted, this is definitely the one that helps me out.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately destructuring is a JS behavior so TS can only simplify this by adding some new construct (`old: new as type` definitely wouldn’t be too bad) on top of the existing destructuring syntax, and obviously they haven’t.